# meaning of "it's less of a drain on resources"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

What does this statement mean?

> He's more comfortable, we are more comfortable, it's less of a drain on resources, the authority is ecstatic.

I can't understand what it means by "it's less of a drain on resources, the authority is ecstatic."

Comment: If you give us some context, and indicate which words are giving you trouble (after looking them up in a dictionary) somebody might then be able to help you.

Comment: I found the answer. thank you.... but I want to now whether " the authority is ecstatic" is an idiom or  a famous statement?

Comment: @user77755: it is not idiom.  It is likely literal.

Comment: this isn't a chat site. ask any basic questions on ELL.

Comment: "less of a drain on resources" is often phrased as "less **resource-intensive**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is from a theatre play in The Methuen Drama Book. Here is the passage from the play [Link](https://books.google.de/books?id=4iCBtRc81H8C&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=He%27s%20more%20comfortable,%20we%20are%20more%20comfortable,%20it%27s%20less%20of%20a%20drain%20on%20resources,%20the%20authority%20is%20ecstatic.&source=bl&ots=54ZU9QYnh4&sig=RkarEca-ueFrjiS5Ig0LXdyDUUg&hl=de&sa=X&ei=rg11VYjxEoT1UJj-gcAK&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=He's%20more%20comfortable%2C%20we%20are%20more%20comfortable%2C%20it's%20less%20of%20a%20drain%20on%20resources%2C%20the%20authority%20is%20ecstatic.&f=false)

It is the case of a person with dementia. Obvious friends or neighbours have taken this demented person to a doctor and advise the doctor to transfer the patient to an institution for such persons. This would cost the community less money (less of a drain on resources) and the authorities would be glad about such a measure (the authorities would be ecstatic if they had to pay less).

Answer (score 0):

The "resources" may signify material abundancies as required in an enterprise, or the emotional availability of a person or his concentration which may have been exhausted in the parallel scenario that might have been described in the context. So the phrase means the people in the context are relieved that their "resources" were somewhat reserved and preserved in the process of doing said event (as in the context)